# $p$th rooth equation when $p=2$ and $p'=3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm  ashamed to ask for help for such a silly equation
here is : 
$$\sqrt{x}+\sqrt[3]{x}-12=0$$
i tried to make everything square 6 but its just too lonngg
any help would be appreciated, this notion is new to me so i don't know what to do

Answer (score 2):

This equation isn't very easy to solve directly. However, we're in luck: The smallest positive integer (greater than 1) that has both an integer square root and an integer cube root turns out to work.

Comment: thank you for this answer

Answer (score 2):

Substitution $$x=t^6$$ then we get $$\sqrt{x}=t^3$$ and $$\sqrt[3]{x}=t^2$$

Comment: yeah i thought about this but got stuck trying to solve $t^{3}+t^{2}-12=0$

Comment: It it $$(t-2) \left(t^2+3 t+6\right)=0$$

Comment: ... what a shame that's was so easy. thank you